# TouchMoved not called for customized GesturesRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm new to iOS development. I currently need to develop a ForceTouchGestureRecognizer with 2-second activation when the user start touch

But, the state for force touch gesture does transit very well after add `holdFor > minimumPressDuration`

It seems that `.changed` a state cannot be reached

There is the console output

[image]

The following is the code for ForceTouchGestureRecognizer class

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class ForceTouchGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

var minimumValue: CGFloat = 0 // Value between 0.0 - 1.0 that needs to be reached before gesture begins
var tolerance: CGFloat = 1 // Once force drops below maxValue - tolerance, the gesture ends
var minimumPressDuration: Int = 1000

private(set) var forceValue: CGFloat? // value between 0.0 - 1.0
private var maxValue: CGFloat = 0
private var touchStartTime: Int = 0

override func reset() {
    super.reset()
    forceValue = nil
    maxValue = 0
    minimumPressDuration = 1500
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        if touches.count != 1 {
            state = .failed
        }
        touchStartTime = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let value = touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce
        let holdFor = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000) - touchStartTime

        if state == .possible {
            if value > minimumValue && holdFor > minimumPressDuration {
                self.state = .began
            }
        } else {
            if value < (maxValue - tolerance) {
                state = .ended
            } else {
                maxValue = max(self.forceValue ?? 0, maxValue)
                self.forceValue = value
                state = .changed
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    if state == .began || state == .changed {
        state = .cancelled
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    if state == .began || state == .changed {
        state = .ended
    }
}

}
```

Source: https://github.com/ashleymills/ForceTouchGestureRecognizer.swift/blob/master/ForceTouchGestureRecognizer.swift

---

Updated on Mar 17 2019

According to Craz1k0ek's anwser. I think it will be good to post my worked code here

```
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

class ForceTouchGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

var minimumValue: CGFloat = 0 // Value between 0.0 - 1.0 that needs to be reached before gesture begins
var tolerance: CGFloat = 1 // Once force drops below maxValue - tolerance, the gesture ends
var minimumPressDuration: TimeInterval = 1.5

private(set) var forceValue: CGFloat? // value between 0.0 - 1.0
private var maxValue: CGFloat = 0
private var touchStartTime: TimeInterval?

override func reset() {
    super.reset()
    forceValue = nil
    maxValue = 0
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        if touches.count != 1 {
            state = .failed
        }
        touchStartTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    guard touchStartTime != nil else { return }

    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let touch = touches.first!
        let value = touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce
        let holdFor = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - touchStartTime!

        if holdFor > minimumPressDuration {
            if state == .possible {
                if value > minimumValue {
                    self.state = .began
                }
            } else {
                if value < (maxValue - tolerance) {
                    state = .ended
                } else {
                    maxValue = max(self.forceValue ?? 0, maxValue)
                    self.forceValue = value
                    state = .changed
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    if state == .began || state == .changed {
        state = .cancelled
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    if state == .began || state == .changed {
        state = .ended
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do want to quote the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1619998-state):

> Special Considerations Subclasses of UIGestureRecognizer must use a
>   read-write version of the state property. They get this redeclaration
>   when they import the UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h header file...

I have simplified your gesture recognizer to have it activate after two seconds. Do note that I see some inconsistency in your code: the `minimumPressDuration` is set to `1000` by default, however, the `reset()` sets the value to `1500`, which might explain some of your behaviour too.

```
class ForceTouchRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    // The minimum time the touch should take
    private let minimumTouchTime: TimeInterval = 2.0
    // The start time of the touch
    private var touchStartTime: TimeInterval?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        // Set the start time
        touchStartTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        // If there is no start time, how is this possible, don't do anything
        guard touchStartTime != nil else { return }

        // Check if the minimumTouchTime has passed since the start time
        if(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - touchStartTime! > minimumTouchTime) {
            print("I should perform some action now!")
        }
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        // Make sure the start time is reset
        touchStartTime = nil
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        // Make sure the start time is reset
        touchStartTime = nil
    }

}
```

I would also recommend taking a look at the [UILongPressGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer) class. This might also have some functionality you're after.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your code and it works! I think the key is to move the "holdFor > minimumPressDuration" condition out of the state check.